# How to create an encrypted swap partition in Debian 6?

Tags: partitioning, debian, encryption, swap, disk-encryption

I am installing Debian and would like to set up the `/swap` partition as encrypted.

I am able to select either encrypted physical device or as `swap/swap`. Are there any methods to create an encrypted `/swap` partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swap partition can hold a lot of unencrypted confidential information and the fact that it persists after shutting down the computer can be a problem.

Encrypting a swap partition however is slightly tricky if one wants to also support suspend-to-disk (also called hibernation).:

**0- Install the cryptsetup package:**

```
apt-get install cryptsetup
```

**1- Setup the encrypted partition as root:**

```
swapoff -a
cryptsetup -h sha256 -c aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 -s 256 luksFormat /dev/hda2
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/hda2 cswap
mkswap /dev/mapper/cswap
```

**2- Add this line to /etc/crypttab:**

```
cswap /dev/hda2 none swap,luks,timeout=30
```

**3- Set the swap partition to be this in /etc/fstab:**

```
/dev/mapper/cswap none swap sw 0 0
```

**4- Configure uswsusp to use /dev/mapper/cswap and write unencrypted data**

```
dpkg-reconfigure -plow uswsusp
```

You will of course want to replace /dev/hda2 with the partition that currently holds your unencrypted swap.

[Source](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/2008/03/encrypted-swap-partition-on.html)

Comment: alternately you can also try this tutorial :http://www.microhowto.info/howto/create_an_encrypted_swap_area.html